# Setting the correct classloader into the spring context within a tomcat container

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, apache-camel

We're running a servlet inside an apache tomcat 7 container. The application uses apache camel and spring. When the application starts, we get this warning logged during startup:

[Cannot find the class loader from application context, using the thread context class loader instead](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-spring/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/SpringCamelContext.java#L178)

How can i tell spring/camel which classloader to use to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the context while defining the servlet itself WebServletContext

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/*.xml
            </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. We're using java based servlet 3.0 config, so i this solved the warning:

    ```rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());```